Booting Cross compiled RISCV binaries on Qemu
I was able to cross compile binaries for RISCV ie., for Andes tech,
I have kernel Image file, fw_dynamic.elf and u-boot.img and initramfs.devnodes files.
I followed the instruction provided by Andestech to get these binaries.
Steps I followed :

I cross compile opensbl and was able to generate fw-dynamic.elf and .bin in path ~opensbi/build/platform/andes/ae350/firmware/

Compiled Rootfs (inc busybox) and generated initramfs.devnodes file at ~/rootfs/disk/dev/ , There was a .sh script, I just had to execute that to generate this.

Edit .config in linux path with


CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE="~/rootfs/disk/dev/initramfs.devnodes" 

and Build linux by make. This gave me Image.gz and Image files in path ~/linux5.4/arch/riscv/boot/

Compiled u-boot by copying fw_dynamic.* files and linux Image files into u-boot path and then by make ae350_rv64_fastboot_defconfig & make ARCH_FLAGS="-march=rv64v5". This gave me u-boot.img

Now trying to use these files to boot using QEMU. Installed Qemu using text


When I execute below command:
$ ./qemu-system-riscv64 -nographic -M andes_ae350 -cpu andes-ax45 -m 2G \
-kernel ~/linux-5.4/arch/riscv/boot/Image \
-bios ~/opensbi/build/platform/andes/ae350/firmware/fw_dynamic.elf \
-initrd ~/rootfs/disk/dev/initramfs.devnodes \
-append "root=/dev/vda rw console=ttyS0"

Not sure if the root device name is /dev/vda, correct me otherwise.
I'm getting below error :
[    0.223322] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    0.224621] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    0.227011] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.227576] NET: Registered protocol family 15
[    0.231335] ALSA device list:
[    0.231823]   No soundcards found.
[    0.232985] Warning: unable to open an initial console.
[    0.234276] Failed to create /dev/root: -2
[    0.234868] VFS: Cannot open root device "vda" or unknown-block(0,0): error -2
[    0.234994] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    0.235251] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    0.235527] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.4.220-21054-gf1d0d3f65278 #4
[    0.235702] Call Trace:
[    0.236096] [<ffffffe00003537c>] walk_stackframe+0x0/0xa8
[    0.236217] [<ffffffe00049e910>] show_stack+0x30/0x3c
[    0.236302] [<ffffffe0004a44ec>] dump_stack+0x6c/0x88
[    0.236385] [<ffffffe00049ebf8>] panic+0xe8/0x290
[    0.236531] [<ffffffe0000020bc>] 0xffffffe0000020bc
[    0.236612] [<ffffffe000002208>] 0xffffffe000002208
[    0.236691] [<ffffffe000002354>] 0xffffffe000002354
[    0.236772] [<ffffffe000001cfc>] 0xffffffe000001cfc
[    0.236857] [<ffffffe0004a46cc>] kernel_init+0x14/0xdc
[    0.236941] [<ffffffe000033e46>] ret_from_exception+0x0/0xc
[    0.237382] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---

I was expecting linux to boot from qemu.
Can someone help me out here, been stuck for a while and was trying the informartion that i found online aswell but of no progress.
Thanks in advance. Any pointers would be help me learn.

You may try to add '-dtb andes.dtb', I add this parameter and run ae350 successfully.
